# Having trouble plotting means of subgroups of data

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have data that describes the a series of observations (sound level) grouped by date and hour. I want to plot the mean sound level per hour for each day with sound level on the Y axis and hour on the X axis and a line graph for each day. Example data:

```
Hour Date SPL

1 18-May 107.9868

2 18-May 106.5656

1 19-May 107.4321

2 19-May 107.8993
```

I have played around with the group_by function but I'm not sure out to do any better than this:

```
spl_mean <- group_by(sound, Hour) %>%
    summarize(count = n(), Mean = mean(SPL, na.rm = T))

ggplot(data=spl_mean) + geom_line(aes(x = Hour, y = Mean, group = 1), size = 2)
```

Which obviously just gives mean for SPL by hour but doesn't preserve the days subgroup.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You are more likely to get a response if you a) provide reproducible data, and b) explain what you have already tried. For displaying reproducible data, if your dataframe is `df`, you can paste the result of `dput(head(df))` here, which will allow us to reproduce a small version of your data.

Answer (score 1):

Use library **dplyr** for calculate mean per hour and day, and then library **ggplot2** to plot your result.

```
df %>%
   group_by(Date, Hour) %>%
   summarise(SPL_mean = mean(SPL, na.rm = T) %>%
   arrange(Date, Hour) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = Hour, y = SPL_mean, color = Date) + geom_line()
```

Comment: This is pretty close. The only thing is that lines look like instead of ending, they connect back to the start of the next data set. See:

https://imgur.com/e1CF2tS

Comment: Before the ggplot line, add `arrange(Date, Hour)` and it should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ggplot` and where D is day, H is hour and V is volume.

```
# setup for demo
library('tidyverse')
df <- tibble(
  'D' = c(1:5,1:5),
  'H' = rep(c(1,2), each = 5),
  'V' = rnorm(10, 100, 5))

# Figure
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = H, y = V, group = D, color = D))
```

This is telling it to do hour on the x, volume on the y and plot different days individually.

If you need to get per day and hour means first then group_by day and hour, then summarise:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(D, H) %>%
  summarize(MV = mean(V)) %>%
  ggplot() +
    geom_line(mapping = aes(x = H, y = MV, group = D, color = D))
```

Then go make it pretty with labs, theme, scales etc.